# creating an image database in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have represented the image now I want to save the image and the description in database how do I do it. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of database are you using? Do you mean by database Ms Access or a collection of several different images.

If you are referring to the database to mean a collection of images, then you can simply use the following method to save the image in a particular location.

```
imwrite( variable name of the image , 'NewImage.jpg')
```